# Alter default value of column in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter

I need to alter the collation of quite a lot tables including all the columns of these tables. I already wrote a sql statement which generates these alter commands for me. So for example I get:

```
ALTER TABLE [TABLE] ALTER COLUMN [COLUMN] nchar(1  ) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS not null default 'y'
```

However I get an error, regarding the default at the end. How can I incorporate the default constraint in the statement above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `default` is an option for `create table`

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You can't change the `DEFAULT` value of a column in an `ALTER TABLE` statement. See the [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax-for-disk-based-tables) section of the documentation. You have to `DROP` the `CONSTRAINT`s (if it already exists) and (re)`CREATE` them. I hope you named your default value constraints if they did already exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Alter table` does not have an option to supply a default constraint so you have to issue two commands; your first to `alter` the column, then you can create its default constraint:

```
alter table [Table] add constraint DF_ColumnName default 'y' for [column];
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I guess its easier to drop all the tables and generate a create table statement instead. Anyways this solved the problem :)